# How do I force an image to fill its table cell COMPLETELY

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, cell

I have read through many forums and tried the solution there but none of them have worked I still have a small gap between all my images. Here is the code:

```
<table id="Table">
            <tr>
                <td id="td1"><h2>~ Curling ~</h2></td>
                <td id="td2" rowspan="2"><img src="../images/curlingMid.jpg" 
                width="100%" height="100%" border="2" alt=""/></td>
                <td id="td1"><h2>~ Curling ~</h2></td>
            </tr>
</table>


#td1 { width: 32%;vertical-align: text-top; }
#td2 { padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 5px; }
```

Comment: I don't see where there'd be a gap in your example. Can you create an example showing the problem on jsFiddle.net?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The image is an inline element and has some white space below it because of how it is aligned with the baseline.

To fix it, try:

```css
#td2 img {display: block;}
```

or

```css
#td2 img {vertical-align: bottom;}
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/WxrvC/

**Note** that you have set 5px padding to the top and right of the image, and I assumed that is for styling purposes.

Also, `id` attributes should be unique on a page, use `class`, much easier to maintain and allows for easier re-use of CSS rules.

Answer (score 2):

different browsers render html elements with different default padding/margins/spacing etc.. you can try reset these like this:

```
#table td {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
#table {border-spacing: 0px;}
```