# How to make img size constrained by cell size

Tags: html, css

I want to make sure that an image put inside of a table cell has its size constrained by the cell size, even if it distorts the image. I don´t want it to mantain the aspect ratio!

Can someone help me?

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your code showing this problem in action?  It would then be much easier for someone to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force an image to fill its table cell COMPLETELY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841455/how-do-i-force-an-image-to-fill-its-table-cell-completely)

Comment: the image then must be flexible so use % instead of px. eg: `width="100%"` instead of `width="200px"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, I guess:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stojanovic/kqo50nLx/)

```css
td {
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td><img src="https://www.bigstockphoto.com/images/homepage/module-6.jpg"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah, it works! I was trying to set the height on the table tag and for some reason it was not working.